# standardized in vs. standardized by

Tags: grammar, prepositions

When do you say something was *standardized by* and when do you say something was *standardized in*?

It is my understanding that *in* is used to refer to a document describing the standard, while *by* is used to refer to the standardization body. Similarly to published *in* and published *by*.

Example: *IPv6 was standardized in RFC2460 "Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification" by IETF*. Comment: It is a tricky phrase because IETF is the standardization body, but not everyone writing a RFC document is a member of the IETF. [Here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460) is the document.

Comment: Your understanding seems to be consistent with your example, where ***in*** specifies *standardized* to within the boundary of *RCF2460*, and ***by*** specifies the agency of *standardized* as *IETF*. Those two prepositions follow that trend regularly, but not universally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ngram viewer bears out your understanding.  "In" has the meaning of inside and applies to documents.  Go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22standardized%20by%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22standardized%20by%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=20).

> Non-standardized copper material Copper material not standardized **in** a
>   European specification but produced and/or used in Europe.

"In" also has a temporal meaning, so you'll find "standardized in 1996."

"By" has the meaning of agency and requires somebody who can act, literally or figuratively.  Go [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22standardized%20by%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22standardized%20by%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&start=20).

> The Personal Digital Cellular (PDC) full-rate speech coder was
>   standardized **by** the Research and Development Center for Radio Systems
>   (RCR)

The actor can be a method (e.g., titration) or a parameter (along the lines of normalization in the data sense).